# Public access to Intel IPU E2000 on C3 and H3 Content

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We're working on a project where we need access to Intel E2000 IPU. According to the GCP website (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/new-h3-vm-instances-are-optimized-for-hpc/), C3 and H3 machines have such IPUs installed. We wonder if these IPUs are accessible for general public GCP users. Look forward to your response, and many thanks for any help!

Comment: Better ask Google about this